# Detect height change of a DIV with jQuery using Resize Plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin to check if a size of a DIV is changed:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

And it works just fine, but I don't want to just detect if a DIV is resized, I want to detect if the height of a DIV is increased or reduced!

How this could be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Using the mentioned plugin, it's easy to detect a resize event, like: $("#unicorns").resize(function(e){
  // do something when #unicorns element resizes
});

Comment: That plugin seems a bit outdated, you should consider using jQuery UI resizable. It has all you could possibly need, including callback params giving you the new dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of the height:

```
var previousHeight = jQuery("#myDiv").height();

$("#myDiv").resize(function(e){ 
    // do something when element resizes 
    if(previousHeight < jQuery(this).height()){
        alert("now I'm bigger");
    }else{
        alert("Now I'm smaller");
    }
    //update previousHeight for next use
    previousHeight = jQuery(this).height();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't .resize just appl to the window object?