# track resizing of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have iframe with auto height. And height is not fixed.
How to track it's resizing?

I need something like this:

```
$('iframe').resize(function(){
alert($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: And did you tried this ?

Comment: How are you resizing the iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Answer (score 0):

See 
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/

They even have an example called `Resizing an Iframe as its content grows`

If you can't apply it to the iframe for some reason use a wrapper

---

This has been asked a couple of times and everyone recommends that plugin

[How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

[Detecting when a div's height changes using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery)

[Detect height change of a DIV with jQuery using Resize Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154989/detect-height-change-of-a-div-with-jquery-using-resize-plugin)

[Trigger event using Jquery on CSS change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671001/trigger-event-using-jquery-on-css-change)

[How do I detect iframe resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286887/how-do-i-detect-iframe-resize)